# AppleScript - How do I detect if a specific button is clicked on GUI and terminate the script?

Tags: user-interface, applescript

I have a script that manipulates a GUI. At some point in the process, a progress indicator appears in the GUI for a few mins. If the user clicks the GUI button `button "Stop" of sheet 1` (so not a dialog button), I'd like the script to `display dialog` followed by `error number -128`. How do I do this? Here's what I tried...

```
repeat while progress indicator 1 of sheet 1 exists
  try
    set button_returned to button returned of button "Stop" of sheet 1
    if button_returned is "Stop" then
      display dialog "Operation cancelled"
      error number -128
    end if
  end try
end repeat
```

Note: I use `repeat while progress indicator 1 of sheet 1 exists` to pause the script whilst the progress indicator is up.

Comment: While you may be able to determine if the sheet/dialog exists, GUI scripting doesn’t give you access to stuff happening in the application (such as buttons pressed), so you will need to look for something else.

Comment: Sur no prob, thanks for your quick response! Very helpful

Comment: Test my answer. Maybe it is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Save this example as usual app to see the correct workaround to solve your problem:

```
global itemCount

set processName to name of current application
set theList to {"Marlow", "Maddie", "Sammy", "Stuey", "Jessie", "Tolstoy", "Marlow", "Maddie", "Sammy", "Stuey"}
set itemCount to count of theList

set progress total steps to count of theList
repeat with i from 1 to itemCount
    
    set thisItem to item i of theList
    set progress description to "Item " & i & " of " & itemCount
    set progress additional description to thisItem
    -- The delay is simply to simulate processing time 
    -- so you can see the progress bar in action.
    -- Exclude this from your code and put your real do stuff.
    delay 1
    set progress completed steps to i
end repeat

on quit
    if progress completed steps < itemCount then
        display dialog "Operation cancelled"
    end if
end quit
```